# Changing Push ViewController animation to look like a "pop" animation, come in from left to right

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uiviewanimationtransition

Right now I am using a segue from storyboard to push a view controller and there is just the one push transition.  How can I imitate the "Pop" transition in code?  Can I do this while still using storyboard for my other transitions in place now?

UPDATE

I tried what is suggested in the first comment here, with some changes.  Here's what I have:

```
UIViewController *dst = [self destinationViewController];
UIViewController *src = [self sourceViewController];
[dst viewWillAppear:YES];
[dst viewDidAppear:NO];

CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGRect f = CGRectMake(-screenBounds.size.width, 0, screenBounds.size.width, screenBounds.size.height);
dst.view.frame = f;
f.origin.x = screenBounds.size.width;
src.view.frame = f;

[UIView transitionFromView:src.view
                    toView:dst.view
                  duration:0.3
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
     [dst viewDidAppear:YES];

     UINavigationController *nav = src.navigationController;
     [nav popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
     [nav pushViewController:dst animated:NO];
 }];
```

This is working almost how I want, but the original viewcontroller is just disappearing instead of sliding to the right.

Comment: You will have to use a custom animation, http://weeny.tk/rF2xe9C

Answer (score 0):

You can create Segue type "Custom" on your stroyboard and create a new `UIStoryboardSegue` class named "popSegue" In the popSegue.m file add this:

```
    -(void)perform{
UIViewController *sourceViewContreoller = [self sourceViewController];

CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setType:kCATransitionFromLeft]; //or kCATransitionFromRight 
[animation setDuration:0.25];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                              kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];

[sourceViewContreoller.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animateOpacity"]; //or key=@"fadeTransition"

[sourceViewContreoller.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

[CATransaction commit];
}
```

In the storyboard editor Select the segue and change the Segue Class to "popSegue".
 Set the Identifier to "popSegue".
Try this and comment for your result

Comment: I'm actually wanting to push a view, but with the transition of a pop.  So the pushed view will come from the left to the right.  Sorry, in the description, I meant left to right, just made a change.

Comment: This is just popping the navcontroller.  I want to push a view controller, but have the transition look like it is popping.